# Solr - always sort specific subset to last of collection

Tags: sorting, solr, solr4

I'm pretty new to solr. How can I make a subset of records always appear in the last position?
For example: 
I have product records such as: (product_id)

```
ABC001, ABC002 , ABC003, ....
```

Each has its own attributes (two different tables): (`product_id`, `attribute_id`)

```
ABC001 (A1, A3, A5), ABC002 (A2, A4, A5), ...
```

I want all products that contain `A5` always to appear last when sorting the result. Is there any way I can achieve this? I'm using Solr 4.10.2.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This might be a good place to start.  Toward the bottom of the page it discusses how to deal with trying to score something lower than other things. (Note that it says you can't really do that.)  One of the suggestions on this page is to push up the score of everything else..  https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

Comment: There's also the sort function in solr, which acts on things after they've been returned.  The page implies it can't be used on a multivalued field, which is what I assume you have. (A1, A2, A5)   Here's the page: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters.  If that is the case, you could consider "promoting" the A5 to it's own field and re-indexing - although if you need to do something similar with A1, A2, A7, A9 etc., that's no solution.